# android google maps: how to use only GPS?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-play-services

i need higher accuracy, to get the location android use network and wifi OR GPS, I need it to use ONLY GPS for the most precise location.

i am building a simple app to track mobiles, the app woks fine but my problem is that even after enabling the GPS on my phone and requesting high accuracy `setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);`, the app use wifi and network to determine my location not the GPS. how can i make it use only the GPS??

in manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

part of my code ..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ...
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createMapView();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); // Update location every second

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

change the location request priority

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

this will help you

Comment: i need higher accuracy, to get the location android use network and wifi OR GPS, I need it to use ONLY GPS for the most precise location.

Comment: Hello. I think PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY uses network and wifi.